# SQL Server stored procedure with XML param takes much longer AFTER call from C# (EF)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

We have a stored procedure which takes an `XML` parameter that can be quite large.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllocationsOver100]
      @PartID int,   
      @Details xml
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @MemoryRecords TABLE (
            PartID int, AppId int, LocGuid uniqueidentifier, [Date] datetime, Level int
      )     

      INSERT INTO @MemoryRecords (PartID, AppId, LocGuid, [Date], Level)
            SELECT 
                  PartID = T.Item.value('@PartID[1]', 'int'),
                  AppId  = T.Item.value('@AppId[1]', 'int'),
                  LocGuid  = T.Item.value('@LocGuid[1]', 'uniqueidentifier'),
                  [Date] = T.Item.value('@Date[1]', 'datetime'),
                  Level  = T.Item.value('@Level[1]', 'int')
            FROM 
                  @Details.nodes('/parts/part') AS T(Item);

      WITH 
            Unitedpart as
            (
                  SELECT * FROM @MemoryRecords
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_GetAllPartsExcludingOne(@PartID)
            ),

            Aggregatedpart as
            (
                  SELECT 
                        AppId, LocGuid, [Date], SUM(Level) AS Aggregated
                  FROM 
                        Unitedpart
                  GROUP BY 
                        AppId, LocGuid, [Date] 
            )

      SELECT 
            DISTINCT(S.PartID)
      FROM 
            Aggregatedpart AGS
            JOIN dbo.udf_GetAllPartsExcludingOne(@PartID) S
                  ON AGS.AppId = S.AppId
      WHERE 
            AGS.Aggregated > 100
END
```

The stored procedure is called from a C# library through Entity Framework.

The first time it is executed (after it is created) it completes in a reasonable time (order of seconds). Any subsequent executions (either from the C# application or through Management Studio) take several minutes.

If we reset the stored procedure (by executing an `ALTER PROCEDURE` command) and then call it with the same parameter values from Management Studio it completes quickly over and over again. But once called from C# the subsequent executions slow right down again.

Anybody seen anything like this?

Comment: Sounds like parameter sniffing. Check the execution plan when it is running slowly, then recompile the procedure (`EXECUTE SP_RECOMPILE '[dbo].[GetAllocationsOver100]';`), and check the execution plan again with the same parameters. You should see that the plan changes. If this is the case and it always runs in a reasonable time frame after a recompile you can set your procedure to run [WITH RECOMPILE](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/-using-the-recompile-query-hint-to-solve-parameter-sniffing-problems-94369) to avoid parameter sniffing.

Comment: Right. That seems to be what's going on. WITH RECOMPILE has sorted it, but it's not ideal.

Comment: It is not ideal, but in most cases caching the plan is a time saver, so it is better to default to not recompile and allow the option to recompile. Out of curiosity, are you recompiling the whole procedure or just the top part that uses the XML parameter?

Comment: Recompiling the whole procedure. You think recompiling the top part would work?

Comment: It is worth a try. Without seeing the two different execution plans it is hard for me to say which part is causing the issue with the parameter sniffing.

Comment: For further reading on parameter sniffing I have done a recently written a fairly comprehensive answer on it, it could be worth a read. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469603/1048425