# MSSQL Parameter consumes more time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance

I have a database, with a table which has around 2.500.000 records. I am fetching around 150.000 records, with 2 different queries to test. First one returns results between 30 seconds and 1 minutes. But the second one, responds in between 3 - 4 minutes which is very weird. The only thing changes is first one doesn't use parameter but second one does. I am running both from C#. For security issues I want to use parametered one but I couldn't understand why does it take so much time. Any help will be appreciated.

First query:

```
        DECLARE @page INT=3
        DECLARE @pagesize INT=300
            string sql = "SELECT  Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1) AS rownumber,Col1,Col2,Col3";
            sql += " FROM my_table WHERE  Col1 LIKE '" + letter + "%')  as somex 
WHERE  rownumber >= (@page-1)*(@pagesize)";
            sql += "AND rownumber <=(@page)*@pagesize; 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE col1 LIKE '" + letter + "%'";
```

Second query:

```
    DECLARE @page INT=3
    DECLARE @pagesize INT=300
    DECLARE @starting VARCHAR(10)='be'
        string sql = "SELECT  Col1,Col2,Col3FROM   
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1) AS rownumber,Col1,Col2,Col3";
        sql += " FROM my_table WHERE  Col1 LIKE @letter+'%')  as somex  
WHERE  rownumber >= (@page-1)*(@pagesize)";
        sql += "AND rownumber <=(@page)*@pagesize; SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM my_table WHERE col1 LIKE @letter+'%'";
```

My server is 16GB Ram, 4 real 4 virtual CPU, Sata disks.

**Edit:** Col1 is Clustered and Non-clustered index.

**Progress:** It turns out that these queries work well on another server. But this confuses me more. Could it be some setting from SQL Server?

Comment: Sounds like [parameter sniffing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/).

Comment: In addition to GarethD's, you should : 1- ensure there is an index on col1 2- perform a count(col1) instead of count(*) 3- update your table statistics

Comment: I edited the question. There is both clustered and nonclustered index on col1. I changed count(*) to count(col1) but it didn't affect at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, it sounds like [parameter sniffing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/), but in the interest of being helpful I thought I'd expand on that. There are a number of articles on the web that 
go into a lot more detail than I will, but the long and the short of parameter sniffing is that SQL-Server has cached an execution plan based on a value for the parameter that does not yield the best execution plan for the current value.

Supposing that `Col1` has a nonclustered index on, but does not include `col2` or `col3` as non key columns then
SQL-Server has two options, it can either do a clustered index scan on `My_Table` to get all the rows where `Col1 LIKE @letter+'%'`, or it can search the index on `Col1` then do a bookmark lookup on the clustered index to get the values 
for each row returned by the index. I can't quite remember off the top of my head at what point SQL-Server switches between the two based on the estimated row count, it is at quite a low percentage, so I am fairly sure that if you are returning 150,000 records 
out of 2,500,000 the optimiser will go for a clustered index scan. However, if you were only returning a few hundred rows then a bookmark lookup would be preferable.

When you don't use parameters SQL-Server will create a new execution plan each time it is executed, and produce the best execution plan for that parameter (assuming your statistics are up to date), when you do use a paramter the first time they query is run sql-server creates a plan
based on that particular parameter value, and stores that plan for later use. Each subsequent time the query is run sql-server recognises that the query is the same so doesn't recompile it. This means though that if the first time the query was run it was for 
a parameter that returned a low number of rows then the bookmark lookup plan will be stored. Then if the next time the query is run it is passed for a value that returns a high number of rows where the optimal plan is a clustered index scan then the query is still executed using the suboptimal bookmark lookup and
will result in a longer execution time. This could of course also be true the other way round. There are a number of ways to get around parameter sniffing, but since your query is not very complex the compile time will not be significant, especially in comparison to the 30 seconds you say this query is taking
to run even at its best, so I would use the `OPTION RECOMPILE` [Query hint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx):

```
SELECT  Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM    (   SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1) AS rownumber,Col1,Col2,Col3
            FROM    my_table 
            WHERE   Col1 LIKE @letter+'%'
        )  as somex  
WHERE   rownumber >= (@page-1)*(@pagesize)
AND     rownumber <= (@page) * @pagesize
OPTION (RECOMPILE); 

SELECT  COUNT(*) 
FROM    my_table 
WHERE   Col1 LIKE @letter+'%'
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

The reason that when you tried this on a new server that it executed fine is that the first time it was run on the new server the parameterised query had to be compiled, and the plan generated was suitable to value of the parameter provided.

One final point, if you are using SQL_Server 2012 then you could use [OFFSET/FETCH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx) to do your paging:

```
SELECT  Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM    My_table
WHERE   Col1 LIKE @letter+'%'
ORDER BY Col1 OFFSET (@page-1) * (@pagesize) ROWS FETCH NEXT @pagesize ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and taking time for explaining :) But the problem is not the indexes. The problem is, in C#, when we directly declare the parameter in sql command, it works faster than when we add the parameter with command.AddWithValue(...)

Comment: You have misunderstood, I didn't say there was a problem with the indexes. When you use the parameter SQL-Server is reusing a cached execution plan, this might not be the best execution plan for the actual value of the parameter you are passing. When you do not use the parameter then SQL-Server cannot use a cached plan because it is a new query each time. This is why you see a difference.

Comment: In [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469603/1048425) I have done on parameter sniffing I have posted example queries that you can test out and see the different execution plans in operation for the same query. Even though you are not using stored procedures the same principle applies. The fact that you are calling the query from c# is irrelevant.