# Huge performance difference between exec of SP and running the statements of sp is solved by alter query (without any change) of the same SP

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today I run into an interesting problem that no one in our 8-person software team have ever seen.

> EXEC FirmSearch 1, 1

That simple sp took 45 sec. to execute in every time. Running the exact same statements inside the stored procedure took less than 1 sec. I create FirmSearchV2 with same functionality. Then:

> EXEC FirmSearchV2 1, 1

FirmSearchV2 took less than 1 sec. I tried to execute modify query (without any change) of FirmSearch sp and the problem disappeared. Now FirmSearch executes in less than 1 sec.
I am using MsSql 2008.

What are the possible reasons of this problem?

Comment: [Parameter sniffing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds.aspx).

Comment: Try the WITH RECOMPILE option. If that makes it faster, see for Nikola Markovinovics comment.

Comment: Execute the 1st procedure like `EXEC FirmSearch 1, 1 WITH RECOMPILE` and if this takes less time then it is now then it is Parameter sniffing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know sql-server so this may be completely wrong, but in another DBMS stored procedures are compiled with the statistics that exists when the sp are created. That is, if data changes a lot the access plan compiled for the sp may be sub-optimal. This may explain why a recreate of the sp improves performance. Check if there are any utility that can recompile the sp without having to recreate it.

Comment: This is almost true, the procedure is compiled when it is first used, not when it is created, and is compiled with the parameters passed on this first run in mind. This plan is then cached and reused regardless of the paramters passed. In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469603/1048425) I have given a simple schema that can reproduce the issue.